# Client Socket connects to multiple sockets and balances load towards a free socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am being asked to design the following programming problem.

Previously when a client sent a request to my application I was required to route it towards a specific port on another server. The server would response in a timely manner and a response would be sent from their server to my server and I would send the information to my client. This worked fine until the load increased and we realized that the other server did not handle multi threaded calls.

I have been given a limited set of ports by the other app so that whenever a load of client requests enters my application I must balance the load among those ports in such a manner that if port A is not free I send the client request to port B and if B is not free it goes to port C. [I know that this is not a correct solution, management wants it to work that way]

All calls handled are synchronous and all ports (requirement from application X) must always be kept open.

My biggest problems at the moment are:

1. Knowing when a port is free. (not waiting for a response)
2. How to push the load to the other ports.

I need some pointers to where to head to. 
Could you please help?

What I have done so far is load multiple sockets into an array of SocketAddress.

```
     Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
        int interestSet = SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE | SelectionKey.OP_READ;
        List<SocketAddress> socketAddresses = FactorySockectConnection.getSocketInstances();

        for (SocketAddress socketAddress : socketAddresses) {
            SocketChannel socket = SocketChannel.open(socketAddress);
            socket.configureBlocking(false);
            socket.register(socketSelector, interestSet);
        }
        System.out.println("Start");

        while (true) {

            try {
                socketSelector.select();

                Set<SelectionKey> keys = socketSelector.selectedKeys();
                Iterator<SelectionKey> keyIterator = keys.iterator();
                while (keyIterator.hasNext()) {

                    SelectionKey selectedKey = keyIterator.next();

                    if (selectedKey.isConnectable()) {
                        SocketChannel connectChannel = (SocketChannel) selectedKey.channel();
                        connectChannel.finishConnect();
                    }
                    if (selectedKey.isWritable() && requestMessageByte != null) {
                        SocketChannel writeChannel = (SocketChannel) selectedKey.channel();
                        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(requestMessageByte.getBytes());
                        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
                            writeChannel.write(buf);
                        }
                        requestMessageByte = null;
                    }

                    if (selectedKey.isReadable() && responseMessage == null) {
                        SocketChannel readChannel = (SocketChannel) selectedKey.channel();

                        ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
                        readChannel.read(readBuffer);
                        responseMessage = new String(readBuffer.array());
                    }
                    keyIterator.remove();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am planning on using a load balancer. I will keep you posted.